# Styling and Mouse Interactions with SVG elements

Tags: svg

I have to generate a polygon from given point list.
But the rendered polygon should have edges where I can manipulate its properties such as fill color, stroke width.Style shouldn't be applied for whole element but need to be applied for each edge independently.

The edges need to be clickable i.e mouse interactions.

How can i achieve this. Is it possible ?

Comment: Draw the polygon with individual lines. I.e. each line will be a separate element.

Comment: @RobertLongson The problem is input is point list.
We would have a JSON format as input , describing the shape type i.e Polygon , Line etc and its Properties. We would have number of shapes as input.
Based on the coordinates  [0, 0], [600.1, 0], [600.1, 400.2], [0, 400.2], [0, 0] , it should render a shape.
We should be able to customize each edge with different style.That is where I am confused how to achieve.
When we apply style it would be applied to entire shape , instead of each edge.Please help me with this.

Comment: @user9757064 whats the problem with a pointlist? You can use it to draw lines from it

Comment: @Fuzzyma  Can you please say me how can we achieve that.I am new to SVG .

Comment: Create <line> elements.

Comment: @RobertLongson  Thank you for the inputs.Let me try out things and I will come back to you if more doubts.

Comment: Can I create d paths from these coordinates , same way as you have suggested for line. Each edge can have a d path from the coordinates instead of  line.I heard d path gives more control over how the segments look.
With paths you can control the border of each segment and the linecap (shape at the end of each segment).

Comment: @RobertLongson I have tried your way, with lines setting properties this way:  `x1: 60, y1: 40,x2: 0,y2: 40,stroke: 'green', strokeWidth: "15"` The problem here is the edges are not connecting.I would attach an file for understanding better.

Comment: Sorry I found I can't upload image in comment

Comment: That's really the best you can do, I'm afraid.

Comment: When you need different colors for edges your only choices are libnes. not path, not polygon, only lines. Yes there edges are not connecting. There is nothing you can do about that EXCEPT making the linecap round. That will help a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with creating SVG line elements, for the edges to connect used stroke-linecap.
I was even able to convert those lines to path for better effects.